# How should you include your dependencies' licenses?

Tags: licensing, license-notice

I have read [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6142/include-library-dependencies-licenses-as-well) and am well aware that you are required to also include your project's dependencies' licenses besides your own in any open source project.

What I don't understand is *how* you are supposed to include them. Obviously you can't have multiple files named `LICENSE`, so what do you do instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no schematic rule which fits all. Do something which fulfills the license terms and fits the way you distribute your project.

E.g. the MIT license requires

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
> included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

The GPL suggests

> If the program does terminal interaction, make it output a short
> notice like this when it starts in an interactive mode:
>
> ```
> <program>  Copyright (C) <year>  <name of author>
> This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `show w'.
> This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
> under certain conditions; type `show c' for details.
> ```
>
> The hypothetical commands `show w` and `show c` should show the
> appropriate parts of the General Public License. Of course, your
> program's commands might be different; for a GUI interface, you would
> use an “about box”.

So yes, you can even have one LICENSE file. You can have folders with one each. You can rename them to like original_project_LICENSE... whatever. Just be clear in what you do and what refers to what modules or parts