# What software licenses can be used in a CC BY-SA 3.0 work?

Tags: license-compatibility, cc-by-sa

I'd like to know what kind of licensed software (e.g. MIT, Apache, GPL) that I can use in such a project without any sort of violation. If this were 4.0, it'd be fairly straightforward as that has GPLv3 compatibility. The issue is that the work MUST be published under a 3.0 license.

The Creative Commons site lacks any sort of information on this particular question, other than that no compatible licenses exist. However, this only seems to apply to attempting to re-license CC BY-SA 3.0 work under a different license, not the other way around.

Comment: Can you be specific as to which license you are trying to reuse and what types of dependencies will there be? See http://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4315/947

Comment: This is more of a very general question, rather than one with a particular project in mind. A sample project would be a CC-BY-SA 3.0 creative project with embedded JavaScript - would I be able to JS snippets licensed under MIT, etc.

Comment: Thanks, being more specific always helps with eliciting answers. General questions are always harder!