# Should I show the dependencies that I use

Tags: dependencies

I am developing an open source project, but need to use a library. The library is open source, but I don’t know if I need to tell the user about the dependency. Do I have to show a license of the dependencies that I use? The dependency is under the MIT license.

Comment: Welcome to Open Source.SE.  Have you read https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4315/990 ?

Comment: If you include MIT licensed software in your distribution, then yes, you need to comply with the MIT license. And the MIT license requires that you include a copy of the license when you distribute the software. So effectively you are already telling a user about this dependency (provided he bothers to read the LICENSE files, etc. in the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is open source, so the user can find out by themselves that you are using said library (at the very least, it will show up as a dependency, or as part of the code). Trying to hide this just comes out as dishonest, making your software suspect. All for nothing.

The whole idea of open source is *open*: Tell (as well as you can/manage) all any user or potential adaptor might want to know up front about the software. You want it to be widely used, so you are doing yourself (and your users) a favor.